# List appsetting for dockerized ASP.NET core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have a dockerized ASP.net core 2.1 application that uses different appsettings.json depending on the environment it is running in e.g. dev, prod, prev. How can i view the current appsetting.json the application is using inside the docker container? I need this to make sure that it is running with the correct settings for the given environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the environment variable using docker run command.

```
 docker run -it -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Development' sample
```

Also, This variable can be assessed from configuration like this,

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

  var environment = Configuration["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"];
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Variable =: {environment}");
```